# Как отсортировать буквы в списке?

Tags: python

У меня есть список с N количеством букв(значений), и мне нужно определить, есть ли рядом с согласными другие согласные, а рядом с гласными другие гласные.
К сожалению у меня нет наработок кода т.к я вообще не понял как написать подобное

Допустим у меня есть такой список
`arr = [”А”, ”Б”, ”Г”, ”О”, ”Е”]`

Я понял, что мне нужно сортировать его как `arr.sort(lambda x: …)`

И после сортировки должен получиться такой список:
`arr = [”А”, ”Б”, ”О”]`

Но что вписать в `lambda` функцию?

Вот условие
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Извините за ошибки, я новичок на питоне

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно точное условие задачи. Сортировка явно ни к чему.

Comment: Вы определитесь в чём задача то. Определить что-то (как в заголовке), отсортировать данные (как в вашем коде) или отфильтровать (судя по желаемому результату)?

Comment: Я добавил скриншот условия. 
Этого достаточно? Или нужно что-либо еще?

Comment: Сначала нужно понять, что требуется в этом задании. И станет ясно, что никакого списка тут нет, и сортировать тут нечего. А после этого начать решать задачу и задавать тут конкрентные вопросы, когда возникнут.

Comment: А как мне тогда генерировать/фильтровать это?

Comment: Я не могу понять через что помимо массива можно решить это

Comment: Это совершенно другая задача. И она недавно здесь была, и ваш однокашник её решил, понадобилась лишь небольшая помощь со скоростью работы. Предлагаю подумать, как вывести **формулу** для количества нужных последовательностей, а не перебирать их.

Comment: Хорошо, я подумаю над формулой. 
А если создать 2 списка(согласных и гласных). И итерировать искомое слово проверяя по индексу наличие букв(из списков)

Comment: В списке гласных только A. Итерировать слова - нет шансов дождаться  конца для длины N уже в несколько десятков.

Comment: А есть хотя бы наводка на нужную формулу?

Comment: Для начала можете и через итерирование. Там нет ничего сложного, просто сядьте и подумайте. Если за вас кто-то сделает, вы ничему не научитесь. С формулой сложнее, но, возможно, после итерирования станет проще понимать что к чему.

Comment: А если написать примерно это `glas = len(re.findall(r'[AEIOUY]', word, re.IGNORECASE))
  sogl = len(re.findall(r'[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]', word, re.IGNORECASE))`